# JQuery wrap element using a html Mustache.js template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, mustache

On my page i have an element that I can get called myobject.

```
<div class="outter">
<div class="somethingElse"><a href="#">test</a></div>
{{myobject}}
</div>
</div>
```

I want to create in the DOM the code above with the `myobject` inside this code.

So the above would become:

```
<div class="outter">
<div class="somethingElse"><a href="#">test</a></div>
<img id="myCoolImage" src="myimage.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Ideally the image with class "outter" would have all the style elements from the img element, but that's not as important as having it insert into my template.

Comment: Is the question how to replace the placeholders with curly brackets, or just how to append an element in the right place, and transfer the styles to another element ?

Comment: @nathanleggatt is your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using a template (Mustache.js?) you can add your `myobject` into your script like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){
   var myobject={img: "myimage.jpg"};       
   var output = Mustache.render("<img id="myCoolImage" 
       src={{myobject.img}}/>", myobject);    
});
```

For the non-template route, you could use the jQuery [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method which inserts content at the end of a DOM element like this (HTML):

```
<div class="outter">
   <some-elements></>
      ...appended stuff goes after all of "outter"'s child elements..
       ... but before its closing tag
</div>
```

and the JS would be something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){
   var myobject={img: "myimage.jpg"};       
    $('.outter').append("<img id="myCoolImage" src="'+myobject.img+'"/>");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

so...your code would look like this:

```
$("myCoolImage").before("<div class='outter'><div class='somethingElse'><a href='#'>test</a></div>");
$("myCoolImage").after("</div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to answer this, not knowing much about how this is supposed to work ?

Assuming it's not a templating system/plugin, and that the point is to replace the curlybrackets with an element, and at the same time move the CSS, I would do:

```
var img = $("#myCoolImage")[0],
    css = img.style.cssText,
    wrapper = $(".outter"),
    wrapperContent = wrapper[0].innerHTML,
    placeholder = wrapperContent.match(/{{(.*?)}}/gi);

wrapper.html(wrapperContent.replace(placeholder, img.outerHTML)).get(0).style.cssText = css;
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3yNpg/) to see how it's working.

This only moves inline CSS statements, and if you need to move styles set in an external stylesheet or in a style tag, you have to look into the currentStyle / getComputedStyle functions in Javascript, but that seems like overkill, when all you really have to do is apply the styles to a class, and add that class to the `outter` element.

​

Answer (score 0):

You can use the triple mustache: **{{{myobject}}}**

and then:

```
var template = "<div class="outter">
<div class="somethingElse"><a href="#">test</a></div>
{{{myobject}}}
</div>
</div>";

$("body").append(Mustache.render(template, {myobject: "<img id="myCoolImage" src="myimage.jpg"/>"}));
```